# How to open only a single find and replace dialog box using java swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have created a notepad application using Java AWT and Swing APIs. I am able to open, save and do everything, i have also created a Jdialog to show the find and replace dialog box into my notepad application.

> My question is that when i click edit->Find, i get the dialog box as many times i click find button, How to get it only one time?

```
final JDialog frDialog = new JDialog();
frDialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));
//frDialog.setModal(true);
frDialog.setVisible(true);
frDialog.requestFocus();
```

I dont want to use the setModal method, I am a fresher, so can anyone suggest me a better method to prevent duplication of dialog boxes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should have spent one day coding it.

Comment: Christopher, I guess you have the misconception that there is a common "Find & Replace" Dialog you just have to reuse. There isn't. You have to make one yourself. There might be something predefined if you were using some platform like Netbeans platform or Eclipse platform. But I never used those so that is just a suspicion.

Comment: @Christopher, please attempt to reword your question to get better answers to achieve what you're looking for. I have edited your question. See if it helps.

Comment: *I have searched the net for one day but could not find anything, please help me.* Quite the quote.

Comment: @Christopher, I updated my answer with a code snippet. You'll still need to figure out the logic of finding and replacing. But I hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: `what comes here??`  Code. Get onto it, as the answer is 'too broad' for this not to be closed. Get back to us when you have a ***specific*** question.

Comment: @anacron, thank you for the code, now i am able to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a modal `JDialog` with required options to capture the search and replace strings. And also provide check boxes for options like match case, regular expression, etc. Add `JButton` buttons for `Find Next`, `Replace`, `Replace All` and `Cancel`. Write appropriate logic for these buttons and finally show the dialog from your notepad's `actionPerformed` method. This should give you a good starting point to accomplish what you're looking for.

> **Update:**

Use this to get a head start:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame notepadFrame = createFrame();
        JDialog frDialog = new JDialog(notepadFrame);

        frDialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));

        JTextField txtFind = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtReplace = new JTextField();
        JButton btnFind = new JButton("Find");
        JButton btnReplace = new JButton("Replace");
        JButton btnReplaceAll = new JButton("Replace All");
        frDialog.add(new JLabel("Find: "));
        frDialog.add(txtFind);
        frDialog.add(new JLabel(""));
        frDialog.add(btnFind);
        frDialog.add(new JLabel("Replace with: "));
        frDialog.add(txtReplace);
        frDialog.add(new JLabel(""));
        frDialog.add(btnReplace);
        frDialog.add(new JLabel(""));
        frDialog.add(new JLabel(""));
        frDialog.add(new JLabel(""));
        frDialog.add(btnReplaceAll);

        frDialog.pack();
        frDialog.setVisible(true);

        show(notepadFrame);

    }

    public static JFrame createFrame(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Notepad Frame");
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTextArea());
        return frame;
    }

    public static void show(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there no other way to call the default find dialog box, like default open/save dialog box into java..?

Comment: @Christopher There is no "default find dialog box".